# How to check input in command line is integer in C?

Tags: c, cs50

I want the code to check input in command line is integer. i.e. 10b is not valid. I tried isdigit() but is not working? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
   if (argc == 2)
   {
       int key = atoi(argv[1]);

       if (isdigit(key))
       {
          printf("Success\n\%i\n", key);
          exit(0);
       }

    }
  printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: I suggest [strtol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtol-wcstol-strtol-l-wcstol-l?view=vs-2017) which sets a pointer you supply to point to the character that stopped the conversion.

Comment: `atoi` does no error checking. And the correct declaration is `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`; the `<cs50.h>` header's definition `typedef char *string;` is a really bad idea. (A pointer is not a string.)

Comment: Do you consider `"1234567890123456789012345678901234567890"` an _integer_.  Math-wise it is, but certainly will not fit in an `int` or common `long long`.

Answer (score 1):

Function `isDigit` checks if a single character is a digit, i.e. in the range between `'0'..'9'`. To check if a string is a number, I'd suggest to use function [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

`long strtol(const char *str, char **str_end, int base )` converts a string `str` to an integral number and also sets the pointer `str_end` to the first character that took not part in the conversion any more. If you require that no characters must follow your number, then `str_end` must point to the string's end, i.e. to string termination character `'\0'`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int isNumber(const char* str) {

    if (!str || *str=='\0') {  // NULL str or empty str: not a number
        return 0;
    }

    char* endOfNum;
    strtol(str,&endOfNum,10);

    if (*endOfNum == '\0') { // string is at its end; everything in it was a valid part of the number
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;  // something that is not part of a number followed.
    }

}

int main() {
    const char* vals[] = {
        "10b",
        "-123",
        "134 ",
        "   345",
        "",
        NULL
    };

    for (int i=0; vals[i]; i++) {
        printf("testing '%s': %d\n", vals[i], isNumber(vals[i]));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
testing '10b': 0
testing '-123': 1
testing '134 ': 0
testing '   345': 1
testing '': 0
```

Adapt the meaning of corner cases like empty strings or NULL-strings to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to use something like:

```
int inputvalue = 0;
if (sscanf(argv[i], "%d", &inputvalue) == 1)
{
    // it's ok....
}
else
{
    // not an integer!
}
```

or something like that. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/

Comment: That does not pick up on the invalid `'b'` mentioned in the question.

Comment: Fair point. I guess it could be extended to do the sscanf, then sprintf the returned value into a string and use strlen or strcmp to check the input string and the result string are the same / same length. e.g. if (sscanf(argv[i], "%d", &inputvalue) == 1) { char compare[strlen(argv[i]) + 1]; sprintf(compare, "%d", inputvalue); return strcmp(compare, argv[i]) == 0; } depends on how clear/efficient you want to be,

Comment: `sscanf` has undefined behavior on numeric overflow. If the input is `999999999999999999999999999`, anything can happen.

Comment: Then, I guess, you could just check the length of the argument and, if it's too long to be a sensible value, tell your user not to be so stupid.

Answer (score 0):

The `isdigit` function checks whether a single character represents a single digit. (numbers − 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9).

In order to check if a string is an integer you could use a function like that. It will

```
bool isNumber(char number[])
{
    int i = 0;
    // only if you need to handle negative numbers 
    if (number[0] == '-')
        i = 1;
    for (; number[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(number[i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: 2 ideas: Allow a leading `'+'` and use `isdigit((unsigned char) number[i])` for correct functionality when `number[i] < 0`.